# How to add a mark as fabourtie icon in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a Quotes app as a beginner in flutter.I have multiple page in my app.Right now i want to create  an icon button which will perform as a bookmark(Mark as fabourite) for the user.So i added the flutter fabourite button in my app.Initially it stays white and when i touch it ,it becomes red,which i wants.But when i move to another page and get back to the previous one(Where the fabourite icon was added) the button become white...I want it to stay red unles the user touch it again.I just want it to be used as an marked as fabourite icon...What can i do now?

```
class p1 extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _p1State createState() => _p1State();
  }

class _p1State extends State<p1> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        body:Stack(
       children:<Widget>[
       Image(
       image:AssetImage("Image/Chowsun1.jpg"),
        fit:BoxFit.cover,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        ),
         Align(alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(' Hello world   '
              ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: "Explora",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900 ) )



      ),
         Align(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
           child: const Text('   1 ',
             style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 25.0,
                 fontFamily: "MonteCarlo",
                 color: Colors.white,
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
           ),

         ),
    Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: FavoriteButton(
          isFavorite: true,
          iconSize: 40,
          iconDisabledColor: Colors.red,
          iconColor: Colors.white,
          // iconDisabledColor: Colors.white,
          valueChanged: (_isFavorite) {},
        )


        )])

        ),
        );
        }
        }
```

Comment: Can you specify how the data is stored?

Comment: BROTHER im a beginner...all i can say its just stored in local database...i didnt use firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not storing the state of the `_isFavorite` anywhere, that's what we use `StatefulWidget` for, is to keep track of state (and changes to it)

At the start of your class, declare a bool to track this value in:

```
class _p1State extends State<p1> {
  bool _isFavorite = false;
```

then later in your build method:

```
FavoriteButton(
      isFavorite: _isFavorite,
```

Finally, once you tap the button, you'll need to inform your class that the value has changed:

```
valueChanged: (isFav) {setState(() { _isFavorite = isFav; })},
```

Note that I changed the argument in your `valueChanged`, because we are now tracking the value in `_isFavorite` (the leading underscore indicates it's a privately scoped variable, on the class. And `isFav` is scoped only to the `valueChanged` method, so it doesn't actually need the leading underscore.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked...just a problem..Before the sign was white,when i touched,it turned  red...but rn it is reversed..its red,and if i touch it becomes white...what can be done,please suggest

Comment: Oh, I had accidentally inverted your default value. Instead of `bool _isFavorite = false;` at the top of your class, put in: `bool _isFavorite = true;`